# How to let org-agenda prompt regularly

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

It would be good to let org-agenda prompt for the items still in the TODO list.

But my list is long. So I'm trying to split the screen to 4 parts, with each part shows a section of the list. As shown in attached figure.

The headache is (org-agenda) always try to split the window itself. The way to get around this is try to export sections of the TODO list into files regularly and use (read-file).

Is there any help on how to write this little function out? I'm not too good at elisp yet. Appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: I do not see how this feature request could be whittled down into a *little function*.  This is more in the nature of a custom version of `org-mode` and `org-agenda-mode`.  It is certainly doable, but would be a major undertaking.  I would suggest that you make better usage of keywords, priorities, tags, title, etc. and work with the sorting / filtering capabilities that are built-in.  If you want the data used by the three (3) primary `*Org Agenda*` building functions, grep for `rtnall` -- that is the list that is gathered and subsequently turned into the `*Org Agenda*` buffer.

Comment: The following link contains a condensed example (requiring moderate to advanced `elisp` skills to utilize) of how to extract the data that goes into creating an `*Org Agenda*` buffer when normally using the function `org-agenda-list`.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  The example does not contemplate the data gathering functions used by `org-tags-view` or `org-search-view`.